# Extracting events from logs

Tags: python, logging

I have a program that logs its work pretty extensively using Python logging module. I want to extract certain events from this log in real time and present them in a nicer format, perhaps a table. Each event's information is spread in several lines.

I have thought about several approaches. I could use regular expressions on the output for example, or perhaps I could write custom logging handlers, although I'm not very familiar with them.

What is the best way to achieve this? If handlers are the answer, some pointers as to how I'd better use them is really appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**
The logging output looks something like this.

```
# misc lines
[DEBUG] Integration:
# a few lines containing several fields about an "integration" record
[DEBUG] End of integration process.
# other misc lines
# other integration records
# ...
```

Comment: If you really want real time, the logging handler is the way to go, as watching the file and processing new output will introduce buffering/polling delays. How to proceed with the logging handlers depends highly on how the program is doing the logging, which you haven't shown. It might be as easy as hooking into the existing logging handlers, or you might need to add in a logging framework or even roll your own...

Comment: I've added a few lines showing how my logs look like.